# Can you specify the differences ./,../,~/ in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

What are the differences between `./`, `../`, and `~/` for specifying an image in my web application?

Like current directory, root, parent directory, etc.

Comment: i think its always better to first google for it. because its really very easy to find it on google.

Comment: @Dr.RajeshRolen, I did, and Google didn't answer, rearranged the questions for semicolons, and /=, /==, which is why i'm here

(came through SymbolHound)

Answer (score 13):

```
"./"  //the current directory
"../" //the parent directory
"/"   //the site root directory
"~/"  //virtual root Web path
```

Comment: +1 for definitions, please provide any example for understanding this much better.

Answer (score 1):

*[ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)* is a very good article in MSDN regarding paths in ASP.NET with good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Web Pathing:

./ means this folder, equivalent to nothing on the front

ex: ./image.jpg and image.jpg are the same thing

/ the web application root folder

ex: /Test/image.jpg, go to the application root, find folder Test, find image.jpg

../ means up one folder then go to the folder after the slash... 

ex: ../Test/image.jpg, go up one folder from the current folder your in, go into folder Test, and find image.jpg.

Physical Pathing:

~/ means the application physical root folder. This will not work if you are using it directly in the webpage (ex: <img src="~/images/image.jpg" />). You can use ResolveUrl to get the web path to a file. I have used this for referencing JavaScript libraries in a master page. I've also seen it used in some custom uploaders.